# falling platforms game maker studio 2

Tags: game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to put platforms in game maker studio 2 that fall when jumped on, but my character stops jumping while the falling with the platform, how do I fix this? Note that my character can jump if the platform rises
here is my falling platform step event:

```
if (place_meeting(x,y-1, obj_player)){
godown = true;
obj_player.vspd_carry = 1;

}
if (dspd < mspd) && (godown == true)
{
dspd += 1;
}
if (godown = true)
{
vspeed = dspd;
}
```

Comment: I think there's not enough information given to help you out. what does variables like `godown`, `vspeed`, `mspd` and `dspd` do? What code is used to let the character jump?

Comment: First thought would be, without knowing the rest of your code is while you are riding the platform down you are not actually in contact with it meaning you are free falling, do you have a variable that holds if you are able to jump or not ? If so check that, another easy to check this would be to use a falling sprite and see if your player switches to the falling sprite while riding the platform down.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot all about this post, problem is already fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding

```
if (place_meeting(x,y-1, obj_player)) || place_meeting(x,y-2, obj_player) || place_meeting(x,y-3, obj_player)){
```

Comment: I've some doubts about this solution, the triple-check on 3 places at once can become process heavy if you apply that too much. Although if it works for you at the moment, then it wouldn't be much of a problem.